# YOCTO - Dropbear denying password

Tags: ssh, yocto, dropbear

I am working on a Yocto-based Linux. I have Dropbear SSH installed. If debug-tweaks is included in IMAGE-FEATURES, I can correctly login via SSH without password. Now, I want to setup a password-based login. So I removed the debug tweaks and added the following lines to my recipe:

```
inherit extrausers
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -P mypassword root;"
```

Now when I try to login via SSH I get the following error:

**root@IP: Permission denied (publickey,password).**

What is the problem? I checked that the password is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The method described by [BelHadjSalem TALEL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68167051), involving modifying the `/etc/default/dropbear` file directly to customize the `DROPBEAR_EXTRA_ARGS`, will work. However, there is a more elegant way to accomplish the same thing.

**Simply add `allow-root-login` to `IMAGE_FEATURES`** in your `local.conf` (or your custom image `.bb` file).

This causes the BitBake plumbing to do the same thing (remove the `-w` flag), without you having to muck about with it or maintain it. As a bonus, it will continue to work even if you switch the image to use OpenSSH instead of Dropbear (by changing from `ssh-server-dropbear` to `ssh-server-openssh` in the `IMAGE_FEATURE` list).

Note that `allow-root-login` is implicitly enabled by `debug-tweaks`, but you can add just `allow-root-login` without turning on all of `debug-tweaks`.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple poky build with a simple meta-test layer that appends to core-image-minimal this:

```
inherit extrausers
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -P 123 root;"
IMAGE_FEATURES_remove = "debug-tweaks"
IMAGE_FEATURES_append = " ssh-server-dropbear"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " dropbear"
```

I started runqemu after the build finished and this is what I figured out:

At first I tried connecting to ssh and it actually denied me.

By default dropbear disables root login, you can find the default file:

```
/etc/default/dropbear
```

its content:

```
# Disallow root logins by default
DROPBEAR_EXTRA_ARGS="-w"
```

So, I removed the "-w" option and I ran:

```
/etc/init.d/dropbear restart
```

I got a successful login on dropbear ssh server.

In addition, you can add this automatically to your custom layer:

```
meta-custom/
    --> recipes-core/
        --> dropbear/
            --> dropbear_%.bbappend
```

**dropbear_%.bbappend**:

```
do_install_append(){
    sed -i 's/-w//g' ${D}/etc/default/dropbear
}
```

Comment: I managed to create an image where the W flag was removed. However this was not the only problem for me, as I could not login even without that flag. I think there is some problem with the password as I saw that the hash in /etc/shadow does not correspond mypassword hash. So maybe that's why Dropbear is denying me. Is your password hash correct?

Comment: Actually you cannot figure out if the hash corresponds to the password because of the "salt" principle in Linux password and users manager. You can try with "ssh-server-openssh" instead of dropbear.